# What does IP address 127.0.0.1 mean in enode URI?

Tags: nodes, enode, terminology

[enode](https://eth.wiki/en/fundamentals/enode-url-format) is the URI for an ethereum node, consisting of `node-id-in-hex@ip-address:port`. Here are 2 enode examples:

```
 enode://6f8a80d14311c39f35f516fa664deaaaa13e85b2f7493f37f6144d86991ec012937307647bd3b9a82abe2974e1407241d54947bbb39763a4cac9f77166ad92a0@10.3.58.6:30303?discport=30301
 enode://a32e5f06c1523c42d732ab8b9bdf569a75d1dad0581ba734b8cc99c5876758132a9b0807b26d79d45cada1a0064db5680efc71350f6030d9a9b1e0a589ef9315@127.0.0.1:30303
```

The `ip-address` is the IP address of the node, such as `10.3.58.6` in first enode example. But what does the `127.0.0.1` mean in 2nd example above? `127.0.0.1` is the `localhost` itself and can not be any other node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the node was incorrectly configured by its owner and advertised the localhost instead of the IP visible from anyone on the internet.
It may come from a setup where the user ran multiple nodes on a single machine for a private network, for dev purpose. But it can be a mistake. Hard to say without more info on where you found these enode addresses.